# Setting parameters during stored procedure execution

Tags: java, sql, java-stored-procedures

Hi I am calling an SP from Java code. This SP has 50+ input parameters. So I set 
`ct.setInt(1, id);` like this from 1 to 50. So if i need to remove say 4th parameter, i need to change all the numbers manually which is a tedious process. Is there any good way to implement this? Some loop way where we dont need to manually change the parameter number?

Comment: Have a look at [Spring JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html). The offer a good [wrapper around stored procedures](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1). We are using this a lot and have good experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you can use named parameters (which I know may not work too well with all databases/drivers).

Or you could do

```
int i = 1;
ct.setInt(i++, id);
//  ct.setObject(i++, old);    // removed line, everything renumbers itself
ct.setString(i++, somethingElse);
ct.setString(i++, evenMore);
```

to keep track of the index.